# Javascript/CSS drop downs not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add css dropdowns to the navigation menu. But it is not working. I would like to know what is causing the problem. Your help is highly appreciated. Here is the link:
[Drop downs to navigation bar](http://www.pinhmct.org/tmp/index.html)

Comment: You don't use a Doctype, which triggers quirks mode in all browsers. That's most likely not what you want. Moreover, there's a [`<script>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) element outside of you `<html>` element. `<script>` elements need to reside within the `<head>` or the `<body>` of a document. I doubt these will be loaded this way.

Answer (score 1):

The error that I get is that ddlevelsmenu is not defined... is there some sort of initialization you have to do for the library you're using?

EDIT: Ahhh, there's the problem.  I looked up this library: you need to be including ddlevelsfiles/ddlevelsmenu.js, but you are not.  Include that, and re-read

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddlevelsmenu/index.htm

to make sure you got everything in there you need, then you should be set!

Ahh! You never closed the tag. Change  to  and I bet you it will work. Those little typos can be the nastiest =

Comment: I have linked the JS file. But I don't see the dropdowns working on hover

Comment: Ahh!  You never closed the tag.  Change

<script type="text/javascript" src="css/ddlevelsmenu.js">

to

<script type="text/javascript" src="css/ddlevelsmenu.js" />

and I bet you it will work.  Those little typos can be the nastiest =(

Comment: Indeed. And Edgar, it's better to edit your answer, the OP will be notified of this. Now you're using a comment without @shivanand, which doesn't notify him (her?).